# Could a data structure be called an instantiated abstract data type?

Tags: c++

It is not clear from what I have read about ADTS and data structures here and else where what the difference between them is. Suppose I have a class that has private data members (an array), and I have functions in it that restrict pushing and popping elements from the data member to occur only from the top. This would be a stack, a specific data structure. But it also would be an ADT:

"An ADT is a collection of data and a set of operations on that data." ("Data Abstraction and Problem Solving with C++", Carrano, pg 17).

But since Wikipedia calls ADTs "purely theoretical entities", is the above class the ADT while the implementation, the object, the data structure?

Comment: Don't be too wound up in this kind of terminology, either. CS is a young enough topic that we haven't converged on a "standard" terminology.

Comment: Thank you Charlie Martin. It doesn't seem like there is overlap and some confusion

Comment: This is why technical papers always -- or at least should always -- start with a terminology section to explain what you think you mean by terms like ADT.

Comment: Is every type which is not an abstract data type, an instantiated abstract data type?

Answer (score 2):

No. 'Instantiated abstract' is essentially a contradiction in terms.

Comment: While it is simply abstract (class), it seems like an ADT. I was asking if the concrete (object) would be called the data structure.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer. If you changed 'instantated' to 'concrete' for example you would then have 'concrete abstract', which is also an oxymoron. There's no need to invent new terminology here.

Answer (score 0):

A data structure is *any* kind of organization of data; ADTs are a particular kind (and use) of data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Well, kinda sorta.  ADTs are a description consisting of a description of the state space, and the operations that are defined against that state space.  So, an integer is a set of states corresponding to the range of numbers you're representing, along with the operations add, subtract and multiply. (We'll ignore divide since we'd have to define exactly which integer divide we mean.)

An integer in a computer program is indeed an instance in the sense that it's a concrete chunk of memory and appropriate code to implement the ADT.

Fred Brooks makes a nice distinction, where Int as an *abstraction* is a specification, the Int ADT is an *implementation* because it fully describes the exact type, and the code (microcode, instructions) that actually can do adding and so on is the *realization*. Unfortunately, that distinction isn't really commonly used except among Fred's former students.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract data type is defined as a set of behaviors and properties, common to all implementations of that abstract data type. A .NET List data type has length, has data and operations on the data such as get front, get back, the sequence of data is ordered, ...
A std::list<> is another implementation of the abstract data type list.
Were you finding a list type in another programming language, you would be able to know what it does from your knowledge of the abstract data type list and how they work in other languages.

And if that list in that language would start painting pictures on your screen, you would rightfully delete that language from your system ;)

You can consider the semantics of many abstract data types fixed. Such as lists, sets, stacks, queues. In contrast, before there is a collective acceptance for an abstract data type, the semantics might vary.

As an example, were you polling opinions on definitions of the abstract data type "fuzzy set", you would most likely not get a single answer.

On a side note, if you look for some more theoretical approach to your question, you might want to search for material on "kinds". There, for example, a generic List, applied to a specific data type 'a to be contained in that list would be called a type constructor, as it constructs the concrete type List<'a> when applying List<> to the type 'a, with List<> being a higher kinded type. (I sure hope I got that one right...). Yet, it is beyond the scope of this answer to elaborate more on that matter.